# Xamarin Forms Android 12 SplashScreen backward compability

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im using xamarin and recently update my targetSdkVersion to 31 (Android 12) and wanted to use a SplashScreen, managed to get it working on a device with android 12, but for lower versions it doesnt show anything just a blank screen

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#242424</item>

        // Set the splash screen background, and icon background.
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#242424</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#242424</item>

        // Use windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon to add either a drawable or an
        // animated drawable. One of these is required.
        // Use windowSplashScreenBrandingImage to add a drawable displayed at the bottom
        // of the splash screen.
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/icone2</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="MySnackbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">6dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity

```
namespace App.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icone", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            UserDialogs.Init(this);

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Popup.Init(this);
            Platform.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("PrimaryColor", out object objectStyle))
                {
                    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(((Color)objectStyle).ToHex()));
                    Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(((Color)objectStyle).ToHex()));
                }
                else
                {
                    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                    Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                }
            }

            App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        }
    }
}
```

[PrintAndroidOld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABQvQ.jpg)
[PrintAndroid12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22jRS.jpg)

Comment: If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Managed to do something that worked, it shows the splash activity on android 11 or lower and the new android splash on android 12 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do something, just doing an splash activity that wont show on android 12 and up

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icone", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
            {
                base.OnResume();
                StartActivity(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
                return;
            }

            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed() { }
    }
}
```